# How to auto mount NFS on to Centos Server

Tags: linux, centos, mount, nfs

I have started to notice that on a few occasions, an NFS file server that I have does not always mount onto a CentOS file server.

I normally have to correct this by using the mount -a command in the terminal.

How can I program the server to automatically mount the NFS fileserver once it boots up?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously we can't give the specifics since we don't know your drive information etc.

See if this helps you  [here](http://mcompute.co.uk/showthread.php?tid=537)

Comment: The link is dead